# Why does the gas compress during isothermal compression, in the carnot cycle

Tags: thermodynamics, carnot-cycle

In this step, the gas is said to release some heat dq. From where does energy come from? The temperatures are the same, so internal energy won't flow. 
But the gas compresses, hence the change in energy for the system is -dq.

Where is this energy stored?

Comment: Hint: Think of the first law of thermodynamics for when $\Delta U=0$

Comment: @AaronStevens Yes, dq=PdV. So the compression is actually due to the piston? And the work done by the piston is first transferred to energy as the molecules (maybe for a fraction of a second) and this energy is released to the sink?(due to the temporary difference in internal energy)

Answer (score 1):

You are doing work on the gas. If it is a piston in a cylinder the amount of work is $W = F \cdot \Delta s = p \cdot \Delta V.$

Microscopically, a moving piston imparts extra speed on the atoms that bounce back from it. That would cause the temperature to go up if there was no thermal contact with a heat bath.

Comment: So the piston is going back on it's own? And the compression is not actually due to the gas molecules?

Comment: No, something or somebody is pressing on the piston.

Answer (score 1):

> In this step, the gas is said to release some heat dq. From where does
>   energy come from

The energy comes from the compression of the gas.

During the isothermal compression of an ideal gas in the Carnot Cycle, work is being done on the gas by an external force compressing the gas. Compression adds to the internal energy of the gas.  However simultaneously heat is transferred out of the gas decreasing the internal energy of the gas by an equal amount, so that the overall change in internal energy is zero. Per the First law

$$\Delta U=Q-W$$

And since $Q=W$, $\Delta U=0$.

Hope this helps.